# Overflow Error When Diving Large Numbers In Python

Tags: python, integer-overflow

I am trying to use a code to look for Wilson Primes for a bit of fun and to get me back into the swing of coding, however, I found that when I try to divide 172! +1 By 173 it gives me an Overflow error. Here is the code I am using:

```
import math
x = 2
while x < 1000:
    if math.factorial(x-1) + 1 % x == 0 and (math.factorial(x-1) + 1 / 5) % x == 0 :
        print(x)
    x += 1
```

Which when I run gives me:

> 5
>
> 13
>
> OverflowError: integer division result too large for a float

I changed the code and found that the error occurs once the number 173 is used as x. Can anyone let me know why this is happening? I looked around but only found answers that said there was no limit to the size of numbers used in python. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the factorial, it is your calculation

```
(math.factorial(x-1) + 1 / 5) % x
```

Since `x` is an integer, the factorial returns an integer. However, `1 / 5` in Python 3 returns the float value `0.2`. Adding an integer to a float returns a float, so Python tries to convert the factorial to a float.

However, Python 3's integers can be any size, but that is not true of the floats. Float values are limited to the computer's numeric processor, usually 8 bytes long, and have a maximum size. That size is exceeded, so Python returns an error.

If you mean to add one to the factorial, then divide that sum by 5, then take the modulus with `x`, you should add parentheses and use the integer division operator `//` rather then the float division operator `/`. I am not sure just what you are trying to do, so I can't correct your code for you. But try the `//` operator.